# Executing command via sudo fails when multiple words

Tags: sudo, su

Running a command with two parts fails with `sudo` but not with `su`.

```
root@hello:/var/www/hello# sudo -u root "echo hello"
sudo: echo hello: command not found
root@hello:/var/www/hello# sudo -u root "echo"

root@hello:/var/www/hello# su -c "echo hello" root
hello
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's normal.

Where `su -c` always passes the single string to a shell (it runs `sh -c "echo hello"` as root, and the shell parses the command), `sudo` *does not do that* – instead it directly executes the command without using a shell.

*(Or at least, when you use `sudo -s` or `-i`, it tries very hard to pretend that it does not do that.)*

As a result, sudo preserves the individual arguments exactly as they were received by sudo itself. So in order to run a multi-word command via sudo, you literally just run it as a multi-word command:

```
sudo -u root echo hello

sudo -u root touch file1.txt "This is file two.txt" file_3.txt
```

(Remember that command lines [are arrays](https://superuser.com/a/1424190). So when sudo itself gets executed as `{"sudo", "-u", "root", "echo", "hello"}`, it directly collects the remaining parameters `{"echo", "hello"}` as the new command – without any additional shell-like parsing.)

If you require the su-like behavior, you'll have to manually call a shell:

```
sudo -u root sh -c "echo hello"

sudo -u root sh -c "touch \"This is file one.txt\" file2.txt"
```